# Recurring timer on Android independent of system clock

Tags: android

I'm looking for a way to create a recurring timer on Android that works independently of the system clock being changed by the user. From my research, this was supposed to be the case with ScheduledExecutorService, but the timer stops firing when the system time is set to the past and resumes when being set back to the present. This timer does continue to work when the system clock is set to the future.

Here is the kind of the code used for that:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d(TAG, "timer hit");
    }
}, 0, 2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

I've then tried to listen for the system clock being changed through the system Intents and restarting the timers when an Intent is received. I catch the TIME_SET Intent when the system clock is set to the future or present, but not to the past.

I created a BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class TimeChangedBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();

    static {
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED);
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED);
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "intent received: null");
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "intent received: " + action);

        if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED) ||
                action.equals(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED) ||
                action.equals(Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "system time changed to " + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date()));
            Timers.resetTimers(); //reset the instantiated timers, in another class, not included here, works correctly when it gets here
        }
    }
}
```

I added the BroadcastReceiver to my AndroidManifest:

```
<application ...>
    <receiver android:name=".TimeChangedBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

I registered the BroadcastReceiver:

```
context.registerReceiver(new TimeChangedBroadcastReceiver(), TimeChangedBroadcastReceiver.intentFilter);
```

Below is my log output when running it with the ScheduledExecutorService and BroadcastReceiver implemented, on my Google Pixel, running Android 7.1.2. I had the system clock set to the current time (2019), then set the year to 2020, set the year back to 2019, set the year to 2018, and then set the year back to 2019.

```
2019-01-09 12:34:31.605 TimeChangedBroadcastReceiver registered
2019-01-09 12:34:31.606 Current time: 2019-01-09 12:34:31
2019-01-09 12:34:33.604 timer hit
2019-01-09 12:34:35.603 timer hit
2019-01-09 12:34:37.603 timer hit
2019-01-09 12:34:39.604 timer hit
2019-01-09 12:34:41.604 timer hit
2020-01-09 12:34:43.271 intent received: android.intent.action.TIME_SET
2020-01-09 12:34:43.272 system time changed to 2020-01-09 12:34:43
2020-01-09 12:34:43.273 timer hit
2020-01-09 12:34:45.273 timer hit
2020-01-09 12:34:47.273 timer hit
2019-01-09 12:34:48.812 intent received: android.intent.action.TIME_SET
2019-01-09 12:34:48.816 system time changed to 2019-01-09 12:34:48
2019-01-09 12:34:48.817 timer hit
2019-01-09 12:34:50.817 timer hit
2019-01-09 12:34:52.816 timer hit
2019-01-09 12:34:54.816 timer hit
***Here, I changed the system clock to the year 2018***
***No TIME_SET Intent is received when the system clock is changed to 2018***
***The timer stops hitting while the system clock is in 2018***
2019-01-09 12:35:02.760 intent received: android.intent.action.TIME_SET
2019-01-09 12:35:02.761 system time changed to 2019-01-09 12:35:02
2019-01-09 12:35:02.761 timer hit
2019-01-09 12:35:04.762 timer hit
2019-01-09 12:35:06.762 timer hit
```

How do I create a recurring timer on Android that works independently of the system clock being changed by the user or where am I going wrong with my current attempt?

**Edit:** Using handler.postDelayed() also does not work, behaving similarly to ScheduledExecutorService

Answer (score 0):

#### Measuring time intervals

Use [`SystemClock.elapsedRealTime()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtime()) to measure time intervals.

This method returns the milliseconds since the device booted, irrespective of system time, and including time spent in deep sleep.

It's a meaningless number as an absolute time (it bears no relation to world time and date), but it can be compared with previous values to measure elapsed time.

#### Invoking a function after a delay

Now, to invoke a function after some time has passed, you can use `Handler.postDelayed`, like this:

```
final long delay = 1000; // 1 second
final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

handler.postDelayed(
    new Runnable() { public void run() {} },
    delay
);
```

Note that **this will run on the main thread**. You'll have to route the callback to a background executor service yourself when it triggers.

#### Invoking a function repeatedly

Use the same code as above, but call `handler.postDelayed()` again after the callback finishes running. Each callback schedules the next.

When you want to interrupt the timer, simply *don't* reschedule the callback

```
new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if (shouldStop) return; // don't run again if canceled after last call
        doSomething();
        handler.postDelayed(this, delay); // reschedule
    }
};
```

Comment: Using handler.postDelayed() also does not work, behaving similarly to ScheduledExecutorService. I've edited my post to include this.

Comment: That can't be right. `Handler` uses `SystemClock.uptimeMillis`, which is similar to the `elapsedRealtime` I mentioned above. It is completely independent of the system time and date. The delayed callbacks will be invoked no matter how the date changes. There must be something else going on here.